# Need help checking if a value exist using JQuery .inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to display an error message when a user types a value in an input field (emailaddressVal) that matches a value in my array (invalidEmailAddresses). But I don't know how to go about it.
Thanks for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='emailAddress']").blur(function(){
        // Actual Email Validation function

            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var hasError = false;
            var emailaddressVal = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val();
            var invalidEmailAddresses = 
            ['aol.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.fr', 'juno.com', 'hotmail.com', 'gmail.com'];     

            if($.inArray(invalidEmailAddresses,emailaddressVal) == -1) {
            alert('The email provided is not from a business related domain');                 

            }


    });


});
```

Comment: `jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: I understand, but how can I validate whatever value the user types. I don't want to hardcode the value

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='emailAddress']").blur(function () {

        var emailAddress = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val().trim();

        if (isValidEmailAddres(emailAddress)) {
            var hasError = false;
            var emailaddressVal = emailAddress.split('@').slice(1)[0].trim();

            var invalidEmailAddresses = ['aol.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.fr', 'juno.com', 'hotmail.com', 'gmail.com'];

            if ($.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses) >=0) {
                alert('The email provided is not from a business related domain');

            }
        } else alert("Invalid EmailID");
    });

    function isValidEmailAddres(emailID) {
        var regexExp = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return regexExp.test(emailID);
    }

});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/dd0dx4b5/1/)
Changes That I did

I added a email Validation Function. Only if it is a valid email address you will proceed for hostname checking.

Correct Format of `$.inArray` is `$.inArray( stringvalue, array)`. So it has to be `$.inArray(emailaddressVal,invalidEmailAddresses)`

emailaddressVal will contain a full email address. First you need to extract the hostname from that full email address. It is done at
`var emailaddressVal = emailAddress.split('@').slice(1)[0].trim();`
So if your email address is `abc@gmail.com`, the above line will return `gmail.com`.

Return type of $inArray is the position at which the passed string (emailaddressVal in your case) is present in the arraylist (invalidEmailAddresses). It will return a value greater than or equal to 0. As per your requirement you have to show the message when you want the host in email id is present in array of host names. You need to do 
`if($.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses) >=0)`

Comment: Please explain what the difference is and why yours works, while the original doesn't. Also, I think that having `debugger` in the middle of your code will throw an error; I'm not certain about that, though

Comment: First, in your code you did `$.inArray(invalidEmailAddresses,emailaddressVal)` which was incorrect. It should be `$.inArray( stringvalue, array)`. Second, `emailaddressVal` is the host name like gmail.com. You passed the whole email address. You had to extract the hostname from the email address. I did it here `var emailaddressVal = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val().split('@').slice(1)[0].trim();`.
Third, you wanted to show an error when email addresses are from `invalidEmailAddresses`. `$inArray` will return value greater than `0` when email addresses are from the domains in array

Comment: You were. Thanks for the clarity Sukanya

Comment: @Sukanya I meant in the answer, as that's part of it. Sorry for not clarifying. Could you edit it in?

Comment: @Sukanya One thing. when I type in a name in my input field without using an @ symbol, I get the following console error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Sure I will update it in the answer. Thanks

Comment: Jimmy I would recommend you to check that the entered email id is valid or not. Only if it is valid then only it should go further. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery inArray test like this.

```
var emailaddressVal = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val();
```

The code beloe test the user input to see if it is in the array and stores the index in which it is located.

```
var inArrTest = $.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses);
```

This code test the inArrTest variable and gets the index of the users matched value.

```
if (inArrTest) {
    // Your error message would go here. //
    console.log(invalidEmailAddresses[inArrTest]);
}
```

You can nest your error message inside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

The original code does not work because the -1 checks to see if the variable is not in the array.

```
$.inArray(invalidEmailAddresses,emailaddressVal) == -1)
```

Sukanya's code check to see if the variable is greater than 0 which is the first index of an array.

```
 $.inArray(emailaddressVal,invalidEmailAddresses) > 0
```